# Multiprocessing performance reducing when increasing pool size

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing

I just deployed a `m5.4xlarge` on AWS to test the multiprocessing performance and I'm getting weird results.

`multiprocessing.cpu_count()` returns 16

```
#home I5-3570K 4cores/4threads, with a pool size of 4 : Computation took 5.15700006485 seconds
#aws m5.4xlarge 16 threads, with a pool size of 4 : Computation took 3.80112195015 seconds
#aws m5.4xlarge 16 threads, with a pool size of 8 : Computation took 3.77861309052 seconds
#aws m5.4xlarge 16 threads, with a pool size of 15 : Computation took 3.26295304298 seconds
#aws m5.4xlarge 16 threads, with a pool size of 16 : Computation took 4.16541814804 seconds
```

Did I do something wrong in my script?

```
# coding: utf-8

import hashlib
import time

from multiprocessing import Pool

#on a fresh AWS linux instance run :
#sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
#sudo easy_install hashlib

def compute_hash_256(very_random_string):
    return hashlib.sha256(very_random_string).hexdigest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    POOL_SIZE = 16 #number of threads of our computer
    pool = Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE)

    ########################### generates strings for hashing
    N_STRINGS = 3000000
    print "Generating {} strings for hashing...".format(N_STRINGS)
    random_strings = []
    padding_size = len(str(N_STRINGS))
    for i in range(N_STRINGS):
        random_strings.append(str(i).zfill(padding_size))

    ############################ hashes the strings using multiprocessing
    print "Computing {} hashes".format(len(random_strings))
    start = time.time()
    hashes = pool.map(compute_hash_256, random_strings)
    end = time.time()
    print "Computation took {} seconds".format(end-start)
```

Thanks

Comment: That's what I would expect when the number of processes is four times the number of CPU cores.

Comment: I think your calculation is too simple to make the result stable. Maybe a more complex calculation is better.

Comment: @Sraw would you have a complex calculation idea?

Comment: A simple way is loop. You can calculate sha256 multiple times. Like 100000 times or even more.

Comment: just tested using a 100000 sha256 loop, it's the same thing on a 96 core instance, no gains after half of the cores.

And CPU usage in monitoring never goes above 50%, weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rule of allocating threads when ever you are doing computational intensive work the number of threads should always be less then the no of cores in the machine.If the thread count is increased there will be race condition and your algo will take more time to give back result

> NoOfThreads < NoOfCores

you can use this code to check the number of cores

```
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

Comment: so there is 16 cores and you are allocating 16 threads but forgot main thread that makes a total of 17

Comment: But actually main process doesn't do any calculation.

Comment: But it is there it is allocating memory

Comment: wait, I'll test it

Comment: indeed a pool size of 15 is faster than 8 and 16. However, shouldn't I get something much faster with a pool size of 15 than 8? the difference is marginal. (post has been edited)

Comment: It depends on your computational algorithm and various other OS factors and also how you implement and reuse your pool

Comment: Note that there aren't 16 cores on this instance... there are 8 cores, each with 2 hyperthreads.  vCPU != core.